# select just date fields

Tags: r, filter, attributes, subset

I have a dataframe of various types (numeric, integer, Date, character).

I want to subset this to just the columns that have a format of 'Date'.  How do I go about doing this?

```
mtcars$dates = '2015-05-05'
mtcars$dates = as.Date(mtcars$dates)

#filter just gives me:     newdf = mtcars$dates
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way using `Filter`:

```
#make a function that checks for the Date class
is.Date <- function(x) inherits(x, 'Date')
#use Filter to filter the data.frame
Filter(is.Date, mtcars)
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the columns, get the `class` of the column, check whether it is 'Date' and use that logical vector to subset the columns.

```
mtcars[sapply(mtcars, class) == "Date"]
```

Answer (score 6):

Package *purrr* has a `keep` function for this:

```
keep(mtcars, ~inherits(.x, "Date"))
```

The `~` and `.x` coding allows the use of `inherits` on each column without creating a separate function or using an anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

`select_if` lets you use a predicate on the columns of a data frame. Only those columns for which the predicate returns `TRUE` will be selected:

```
library(dplyr)
select_if(mtcars, function(x) inherits(x, 'Date'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the above answers helpful, but I ultimately came up with a current tidyverse solution with a little help from the `lubridate` package to avoid creating my own anonymous function.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "make_model") %>% 
  mutate(
    start_date = as.Date("2022-01-01"),
    end_date = as.Date("2022-01-31"),
    POSIXct = as.POSIXct("2022-01-05")
  ) 
      
my_mtcars %>%
  select(where(is.Date))
```

Note, this only returns the `start_date` and `end_date` columns, but lubridate has the function `is.POSIXt()` for objects with other date-time classes.

```r
my_mtcars %>%
  select(where(~ is.Date(.x) | is.POSIXt(.x)))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$dates = '2015-05-05'
mtcars$dates = as.Date(mtcars$dates)
head(mtcars)

v=sapply(mtcars,class) #get the class of each column
datecol=names(v)[v=='Date'] # select the columns having date class
mtcars[datecol] #subset those columns.
```

Comment: this is basically the same as @akrun 's answer (only more convoluted)

Comment: I had not seen his answer when I answered the question but you are right. His solution is more elegant.